# NET 6/7/8 - OpenXML Updating Charts

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I'm working on an application where I will be filling out a Word document with some text and want to update some charts.

I have successfully done everything I wanted so far using OpenXML. However I cannot get the Chart to update. The chart's embedded Excel has been updated using OpenXML, but the chart itself does not update. I imagine there is some cache that needs to be refreshed.

Any ideas how this can be done?

```
    private static void PopulateChart(WordprocessingDocument document, string contentControlName, List<List<decimal>> cellValues)
    {
        // Find drawing by alternative name
        var drawing = document.MainDocumentPart?.Document.Body?.Descendants<Drawing>()
            .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Inline?.DocProperties?.Description?.Value == contentControlName);

        // Get the chart reference
        var chartRef = drawing?.Descendants<ChartReference>().FirstOrDefault();

        // Make sure the chart exists
        if (chartRef == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(chartRef.Id))
        {
            // TODO ADD SERILOG
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"Chart {contentControlName} not found or does not have a reference.");
        }
        
        var chartId = chartRef.Id.ToString()!;
        var chartPart = (ChartPart) document.MainDocumentPart?.GetPartById(chartId)!;
        
        var embeddedExcel = chartPart.EmbeddedPackagePart!;

        if (embeddedExcel == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"Chart {contentControlName} embedded Excel resource not found.");
        }

        using var stream = embeddedExcel.GetStream();
        using var excelDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true);

        // Get the worksheet part by name or index
        var workbookPart = excelDoc.WorkbookPart!;
        var worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        
        // Load cell data.
        var cells = worksheetPart.Worksheet
            .Descendants<Cell>()
            .ToArray();
        
        // Start from row 2
        var rowIndex = 2;
        
        foreach (var row in cellValues)
        {
            // Column number
            var columnLetterNumericalIndex = 0;
            
            foreach (var column in row)
            {
                var cellReference = $"{GetColumnName(columnLetterNumericalIndex)}{rowIndex}";
                cells.Single(c => c.CellReference == cellReference).CellValue = new CellValue(column);
                columnLetterNumericalIndex++;
            }
            
            rowIndex++;
        }

        // Save the changes to the spreadsheet
        chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

        // Document is saved higher up (document.Save())
    }
```

Word Interop can't be used as the application will be hosted in Azure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `<c:numCache>` elements in the chart part.

I don't know what type of chart you have nor its formatting options (like does it have a "Switch Row/Column" option), but nevertheless, here is a sample that would update a simple/default Bar chart:

```cs
// ...

int seriesIndex = 0;
foreach (var numCache in chartPart.ChartSpace.Descendants<NumberingCache>())
{
    var points = numCache.Descendants<NumericPoint>().ToList();

    for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < points.Count; pointIndex++)
        points[pointIndex].NumericValue.Text = cellValues[pointIndex][seriesIndex].ToString();

    seriesIndex++;
}

// Save the changes to the spreadsheet
chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

// Document is saved higher up (document.Save())
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the great solution from Mario Z, this method will do all of the necessary heavy lifting to update the series values for a given chart.

```
/// <summary>
/// Update the series values for a given chart. We must update two components:
/// * Embedded worksheet series values
/// * Cached chart series values, which come from the embedded worksheet series values but don't refresh unless you edit them in PowerPoint itself
/// </summary>
/// <param name="chartPart">Chart part to update</param>
/// <param name="chartSeriesValues">Chart series values for the chart - we are only updating cell values in column B for rows >= 2</param>
public void UpdateChartSeriesValues(ChartPart chartPart, double[] chartSeriesValues)
{
    EmbeddedPackagePart embeddedExcel = chartPart.EmbeddedPackagePart!;
    if (embeddedExcel == null)
    {
        // Embedded Excel resource not found - don't update
        return;
    }

    // Get the embedded worksheet part and its cells
    using Stream stream = embeddedExcel.GetStream();
    using SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true);
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = excelDoc.WorkbookPart!;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
    Cell[] cells = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().ToArray();

    // Update the embedded worksheet series values
    int dataServicesValuesIndex = 0;
    foreach (Cell cell in cells)
    {
        // Only process column B and rows >= 2
        string colIndex = GetColumnIndex(cell.CellReference!);
        int rowIndex = GetRowIndex(cell.CellReference!);
        if (colIndex == "B" && rowIndex >= 2 && dataServicesValuesIndex < chartSeriesValues.Length)
        {
            // Cells are in Row, Column order, e.g. A1, B2, A2, B2, C1, C2 ...
            cell.CellValue = new(chartSeriesValues[dataServicesValuesIndex++]);
        }
    }
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

    // Update the cached chart series values
    foreach (NumberingCache? numCache in chartPart.ChartSpace.Descendants<NumberingCache>())
    {
        List< NumericPoint> points = numCache.Descendants<NumericPoint>().ToList();

        try
        {
            for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < points.Count; pointIndex++)
            {
                points[pointIndex].NumericValue!.Text = chartSeriesValues[pointIndex].ToString();
            }

            // Only do this once
            break;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    // Save the changes to the chart
    chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();
}
```